# jqWidgets: How can I post an HTML form inside a jqxWindow?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I created the following HTML form inside a jqxWindow widget for a Laravel project:

```
<div id="provinceWindow">
    <div id="provinceWindowHeader"></div>
    <div id="provinceWindowContent">
        <form id="provinceForm" method="POST" action="{{route('province.store')}}">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <input type="hidden" name="provinceId" id="provinceId" value=""/>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-6"><label>English province name</label></div>
               <div class="col-6"><input type="text" name="provinceNameEn" id="provinceNameEn" maxlength="20"/></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-6"><label>Spanish province name</label></div>
                <div class="col-6"><input type="text" name="provinceNameSp" id="provinceNameSp" maxlength="20"/></div>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
                <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-sm col-3" />
                <span class="spacer"></span>
                <input type="button" value="Cancel" id="cancelBtn" class="btn btn-sm col-3" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var datarow = null;
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}
    });


    //-----------------------------
    // Window settings
    //-----------------------------

    $('#provinceWindow').jqxWindow({
        autoOpen: false,
        isModal: true,
        width: 400,
        height: 160,
        resizable: false,
        title: 'Province name',
        cancelButton: $('#cancelBtn'),
        initContent: function () {
            $('#submitBtn').jqxButton();
            $('#submitBtn').on('click', function () {
                $('#provinceForm').submit();
            });
        }
    }).css('top', '35%');
```

The file routes\web.php has only one resourse route defined for this page:

```
// Routes for province maintenance
Route::resource('province', 'provinceController');
```

Checking the available routes with `php artisan route:list` command, I get these:

```
Method     URI                       Name              Action                                         
GET|HEAD   /                                           APP\Http\Controllers\homeController@index      
GET|HEAD   province                  province.index    APP\Http\Controllers\provinceController@index  
POST       province                  province.store    APP\Http\Controllers\provinceController@store  
GET|HEAD   province/create           province.create   APP\Http\Controllers\provinceController@create 
GET|HEAD   province/{province}       province.show     APP\Http\Controllers\provinceController@show   
PUT|PATCH  province/{province}       province.update   APP\Http\Controllers\provinceController@update 
DELETE     province/{province}       province.destroy  APP\Http\Controllers\provinceController@destroy
GET|HEAD   province/{province}/edit  province.edit     APP\Http\Controllers\provinceController@edit
```

My controller action:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $fields = $request->all();
    if ($request->provinceId == '') { 
        $province = new province($fields);
        $validator = Validator::make($fields, $province->rules());
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        } 
        else {
            $province->save();
        }
        return view('province/index');
   }
}
```

The form is shown on top of a jqxGrid widget, as a modal window, in order to capture the required information and perform the CRUD operations for the corresponding DB table.

The problem is, when I click the "Submit" button the window is closed and nothing else happens. The form is not posted to the indicated *action* and the data entered get lost.

It does not matter if I initialize the ***submitBtn*** inside the ***initContent*** or outside of it. The form is never posted. 
I also tried the *Close* event of the jqxWindow to no avail.

If I take a look to the generated HTML it looks like this:

```
<form id="provinceForm" method="POST" action="http://mis:8080/province">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="Y9dF5PS7nUwFxHug8Ag6PHgcfR4xgxdC43KCGm07">
    <input type="hidden" name="provinceId" id="provinceId" value="">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <label>English province name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <input type="text" name="provinceNameEn" id="provinceNameEn" maxlength="20">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <label>Spanish province name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <input type="text" name="provinceNameSp" id="provinceNameSp" maxlength="20">
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
        <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-sm col-3 jqx-rc-all jqx-button jqx-widget jqx-fill-state-normal" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
        <span class="spacer"></span>
        <input type="button" value="Cancel" id="cancelBtn" class="btn btn-sm col-3">
    </div>
</form>
```

Pressing the submit button takes me to the home page and nothing gets added to the DB table.
I guess the issue has something to do with Laravel routes because I get no errors.

What is missing or what is wrong with this approach?
Any light is appreciated.

Comment: Initially the form contained the jqxWindow, but later I changed to the opposite to keep all the form script inside the jqxWindow and because when the window is closed its content disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, because I erroneously added in my Model a validation, that was not needed, for a column (there was already a constraint defined at the DB table level), it was not possible to fulfill the validator when saving a new record. I commented that line in my Model and, that was it!

```
protected $rules = array(
    'provinceNameEn'  => 'required|alpha|max:20',
    'provinceNameSp' => 'required|alpha|max:20'
    //'deleted' => 'required|in:M,F'  // This is already validated in a DB constraint.
);
```

I noticed the control was returned to my home page but without any message or error, but if you pay attention to my controller it was precisely the behavior programmed. However, there is no implementation to display the error messages, so I added `dd($validator);` before that `return` statement. There I read the message and finally found the solution.

Comment: In the end, I can tell there is no problem at all to have a <form> inside a jqxWindow widget. They work perfectly fine and had nothing to do with the web routes. If you get any issue, just take a look to your code, because something else is triggering the problem.